# error TS2339 property does not exist on component how would i fix this?

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to figure out why my employee property doesnt exist in the TS when it was definded by the array in in the TS file, i did try setting "strict" to false to allow the date through but its still not wanting to bind. down below is my TS code along with the HTML to render it to the DOM.

contact-list component.ts:

```js
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Employee} from 'src/app/models/employee ';
import {EmployeeService} from 'src/app/services/employee.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.css']
}) 
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {
  //store list of employees 
  listofEmployees: Employee[] = [];
  constructor(private myEmployeeService: EmployeeService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.myEmployeeService.getAllEmployees().subscribe(response => {
          this.listofEmployees = response;
      })
  }
  deleteEmployee(id: number) {
      this.myEmployeeService.deleteEmployee(id).subscribe(response => {
          this.ngOnInit();
      })
  }
}
```

contact-list.component.html:

```html
<hr>
<h3>List of Employees</h3>
<hr>
<div *ngFor="let e of listofEmployees">
   <a routerLink="contactlist/{{employee.id}}">
      <p>{{employee.id }}. {{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</p>
   </a>
   <button (click)="deleteEmployee(employee.id)">Delete Contact</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `employee` variable doesn't exist in the component. Probably you mean `e` instead of `employee` based on `*ngFor="let e of listofEmployees"`.

Comment: Alright but now it's only rendering the idea to the DOM not first name, last name, and phonenumber

Comment: Maybe you can provide sample data and error image to the question or create a Minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).